# push is not a function vuejs

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm making an app with **VueJS** and **Laravel**. I'm getting an error, the push is not a function when I clicked an add to cart button. Everything is working here fine but methods addToCart gives error push is not a function. when I first click add to cart button it gives that error and once I refresh the page I can see a product in cart and again if click adds to cart button this time error is not seen, works perfectly. when cart[] is empty it gives error push is not a function, but when cart[] has at least one element I don't get that error.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**productlist.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-7">


<div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
  <div class="card-body">
    <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
    <p class="card-text">{{ product.price }}


    </p>

    <button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addProductToCart(product)">Add to cart</button>
  </div>
</div>

    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default{
        props:['product'],
        data(){
            return{



            }
        },

        methods:{
            addProductToCart(product){

                axios.post('/products/create',{

                    product : product
                }).then((response)=>{
                console.log(response)
                this.$emit('addedToCart',product)



            });

            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

**cart.vue**

```
<template>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <li v-for="(item,index) in cart">
            {{ item.name }}-{{ item.price }}
            <button @click="removeitem(index)">Remove</button>
        </li>

    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
    export default{
        props:['cart'],

        }
</script>
```

**Main.vue**

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div class="col-md-7" v-for="product in products">
            <Productlist :product="product" @addedToCart="addedToCart"></Productlist>
        </div>
        <Cart :cart="cart" ></Cart>
    </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
import Productlist from './Productlist';
import Cart from './Cart';

    export default{
        data(){
            return{
                products:[],
                cart: [ ]
            }
        },
        mounted() { 

            //get all products and show in page
            axios.get('/products')
            .then((response)=>{
                this.products = response.data;
            });

            // get only those products that are added to cart
            axios.get('/list')
            .then((response)=>{
                this.cart= response.data;
                console.log(response)
            });
        },
        methods:{
            addedToCart(product){


                this.cart.push(product)
            }
        },
        components:{Productlist,Cart}
    }
</script>
```

Comment: could it be that in `this.cart= response.data`  the property `response.data` is **not** an array?

Comment: @JaromandaX yes response.data is not array , it is string how do i make it work now. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

i don't sure if this will resolve your problem but is unnecessary do:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" @click="addProductToCart(product)">Add to cart</button>
```

because you have `product` as prop of the component, should be `@click="addProductToCart"` without problem.
and your method should be so:

```
addProductToCart() {
  axios
    .post('/products/create', {
      product: this.product,
    })
    .then(response => {
      console.log(response);
      this.$emit('addedToCart', this.product);
    });
}
```

One thing more, use kebab-case to call the key string when you emit to the parent component:

```
this.$emit('addedToCart', this.product);
```

replace it with:

```
this.$emit('added-to-cart', this.product);
```

Then in your parent component you have:

```
<Productlist :product="product" @addedToCart="addedToCart"></Productlist>
```

replace it with:

```
<Productlist :product="product" @added-to-cart="addedToCart"></Productlist>
```

I guess this last things will resolve your problem according the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html).